# Sphinx docxbuilder and custom extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have a custom node defined in an extension (in a similar way as [TODO example on sphinx page](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/todo.html)).

Problem is that this extension is used for html output via visit_my_node/depart_my_node methods, but I would have liked to implement a similar thing for docxbuilder.

I saw in docxbuilder documentation that I should probably use a translator, but I can't really figure out how, being not very familiar with the concept.

I also saw [this topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981530/new-sphinx-builder-and-extensions), suggesting I should maybe rebuild the builder, but I wanted to maybe get some valuable opinion on translator.

Below, you'll find a code example (a bit old but you should get the idea of what is done) of the extension implementation for the custom node

```
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import directives
from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive


class myNode(nodes.General, nodes.Element):
    def __init__(self, options, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myNode, self).__init__(options, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__options = options

    def get_options(self):
        return self.__options
    
    
class myDirective(Directive):
    """
    Requirement entry.
    """
    
    has_content = True
    required_arguments = 0
    optional_arguments = 0
    final_argument_whitespace = False
    option_spec = {
        'name': directives.unchanged_required,
        'title': directives.unchanged_required,
        'parents': directives.unchanged} # boolean}

    def run(self):
        my_node = myNode(self.options)
        self.state.nested_parse(self.content, self.content_offset, my_node )
        return [my_node]
    
def visit_my_node(self, node):
    
    name = node.get_options()['name']
    
    if len(node.get_options()['parent']) > 0:
        parent = ", ".join([x.strip() for x in node.get_options()['parent'].split(',')])
    else:
        parent = "design"
    
    self.body.append('<div class="mynode">\n')
    self.body.append('\t<p class="my-header"><strong>' + name + '; ' + parent + '</strong></p>\n')
    self.body.append('\t<div class="my-content">\n')

def depart_my_node(self):
    self.body.append('\t</div>\n')
    self.body.append('\t<p class="my-footer"><strong>END</strong></p>\n')
    self.body.append('</div>\n')

def setup(app):
    app.add_node(myNode,
                 html=(visit_my_node, depart_my_node))
                 
    app.add_directive("mynode", myDirective)
    
    return {'version' : '0.1'}
```

Comment: Should the conversion from `html` to `docx` converter solve your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question? I use docxbuilder extension to create a docx delivery of my spec, but it does not take into account the custom node that I shared in this topic.

What is the html to docx converter you are refering to?

Comment: I mean that the output that shows in your script creates an `html` formatted document. Instead of restructuring this output into `docx`, you can simply convert the `html` into `docx` directly.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/htmldocx/

Comment: OK, not sure it's what I'm looking for, for several reasons. I might give it a try but I'd prefer to handle this through extensions and custom directives if there is a way to.

Comment: Still was unable to find a way to make it word, htmltodocx is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output code is not too complex (for instance just some div-container, paragraphs, some text) I would try to avoid the custom builder visitor functions. Mainly as you need to maintain one solution for each builder, and as there are many builders, you may miss some.

I would try to transform your custom directive node to some standard docutils nodes, so that each builder can handle it.

So you can add a handler to the sphinx event `doctree-resolved`, then you search for your custom node in the current doctree.
This node get then replaced by a nested list of standard docutil nodes, e.g. `node.replace_self(docutils.nodes.Text('Some simple text'))`.

The creation of this nested docutils-node-tree for your directive may be more complex than just adding a HTML-string in a visitor function. But the benefit is, you have to do it only once and support 100% of all Sphinx builders out of the box.

Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of [Sphinx-Needs](https://github.com/useblocks/sphinx-needs), which is using the above mechanism for all its directives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I'm not really sure how to transform from a custom to a standard docutils node.

I've been able to implement a working solution by going through docxbuilder source code and trying to understand the code I had to use to make it work, and it seems to be OK. But it might not be the easiest to maintain long-term, so I might be interested by your suggestion.

Comment: Btw, I will test sphinx-needs because I didn't know about the module but it seems to really cover my needs. Again, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I tried to used Sphinx-Needs in a first time which almost made me do perfectly what I wanted, but I did not need my directive to be put in a table for several reason.

So I came back here to understand precisely what you suggest to do, and understood it better reading your amazing Sphinx-Need (maybe one day I'll definitely swap).

In the end I was able to do precisely what I wanted thanks to you. Thank you very much sir!